# progressbar при загрузке документа из БД. C#, DevExpress

Tags: c#, sql-server, devexpress, progress-bar

Как настроить progressbar, чтобы отображал загрузку документ из БД. Документ вытягиваю запросом

```
sqlCommand.CommandText = "SELECT Document FROM [Documents] WHERE 
IdDocuments=@idDoc";
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@idDoc", SqlDbType.Int);
```

Comment: при таком подходе - никак. Самое большее - можно повесить какой-нибудь индикатор ожидания загрузки, но без указания количества загруженного. Если файлы действительно большие - можно получать их по частям и между выполнением запросов на загрузку очередной части менять состояние progressbar

Comment: Какую именно СУБД используете? В SqlServer, пожалуй, можно реализовать получение прогресса при использовании `FILESTREAM`.

Comment: Да, использую SQL Server

Comment: Дальше делаю так 
                sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 120;
                if (sconn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                    sconn.Open();
                fileByteArray = (byte[])sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();
                System.IO.MemoryStream mStream = new 
                System.IO.MemoryStream(fileByteArray);

Comment: Я имею в виду тип столбцов [FILESTREAM](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb895234(v=sql.105).aspx).

Comment: тип - varbinary(max)

Comment: С `varbinary` прогресс не сделать. А вот если поменяете тип столбца на `filestream`, то можно будет. Только предварительно почитайте по ссылке о достоинствах и недостатках этого типа. Он выгоден только при больших размерах документов. Судя по тому, что понадобился прогресс, это именно ваш случай.